# Can this c# async process be more performant?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I am working on a program which makes multiple json calls to retrieve it's data.
The data however is pretty big and when running it without async it takes 17 hours to fully process.

The fetching of the data goes as follows:

- Call to a service with a page number (2000 pages in total to be processed), which returns 200 records per page.
- For each record it returns, an other service needs to be called to receive the data for the current record.

I'm new to the whole async functionality and I've made an attempt using async and await and already made a performance boost but was wondering if this is the correct way of using it and if there are any other ways to increase performance?

This is the code I currently have:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MainAsyncCall().Wait();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static async Task MainAsyncCall()
    {
        ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 999999;

        List<Task> allPages = new List<Task>();

        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            var page = i;
            allPages.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => processPage(page)));
        }

        Task.WaitAll(allPages.ToArray());

        Console.WriteLine("Finished all pages");
    }

    public static async Task processPage(Int32 page)
    {
        List<Task> players = new List<Task>();
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            string url = "<Request URL>";
            var response = client.GetAsync(url).Result;
            var content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            dynamic item = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(content);

            dynamic data = item.data;
            var localPage = page;
            Console.WriteLine($"Processing Page: {localPage}");
            foreach (dynamic d in data)
            {
                players.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => processPlayer(d, localPage)));
            }
        }

        Task.WaitAll(players.ToArray());
        Console.WriteLine($"Finished Page: {page}");
    }

    public static async Task processPlayer(dynamic player, int page)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            string url = "<Request URL>";
            HttpResponseMessage response = null;

            response = client.GetAsync(url).Result;

            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            dynamic item = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(content);

            Console.WriteLine($"{page}: Processed {item.name}");
        }
    }
```

Any suggestion is welcome!

Comment: Remove `Task.Factory.StartNew` and just call `processPlayer`

Comment: Repalce `Task.WaitAll` with `await Task.WaitAll`

Comment: As long as you keep this in a `ThreadPool` `SynchronizationContext`

Comment: `await Task.WaitAll` gives a compile error because you cannot await a void. and without the `Task.Factory.StartNew` it processed one page after the other instead of multiple at a time.

Comment: it is `await Task.WhenAll()`

Comment: Make sure you're using `await` for your asynchronous calls all the way up or your app won't wait for them to complete!

Comment: Use a profiling tool to analyse exactly where your CPU cycles are being spent.  All of the suggestions *could* be bottlenecks - but you won't truly know *the* bottleneck until you profile.

Comment: You can use Parallel.ForEach if you have enumerables to process. It is very easy to use and removes some WaitAll garbage.

Comment: @eocron06 `Parallel.ForEach` isn't a simple alternative to async/await - they do very different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what it should look like to me:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // it's okay here to use wait because we're at the root of the application
    new AsyncServerCalls().MainAsyncCall().Wait();

    Console.ReadKey();
}

public class AsyncServerCalls
{
// dont use static async methods
public async Task MainAsyncCall()
{
    ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 999999;

    List<Task> allPages = new List<Task>();

    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        var page = i;
        allPages.Add(processPage(page));
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(allPages.ToArray());

    Console.WriteLine("Finished all pages");
}

public async Task processPage(Int32 page)
{
    List<Task> players = new List<Task>();
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        string url = "<Request URL>";
        var response = await client.GetAsync(url)// nope .Result;
        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); // again never use .Result;
        dynamic item = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(content);

        dynamic data = item.data;
        var localPage = page;
        Console.WriteLine($"Processing Page: {localPage}");
        foreach (dynamic d in data)
        {
            players.Add(processPlayer(d, localPage)); // no need to put the task unnecessarily on a different thread, let the current SynchronisationContext deal with that
        }
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(players.ToArray()); // always await a task in an async method
    Console.WriteLine($"Finished Page: {page}");
}

public async Task processPlayer(dynamic player, int page)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        string url = "<Request URL>";
        HttpResponseMessage response = null;

        response = await client.GetAsync(url); // don't use .Result;

        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        dynamic item = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(content);

        Console.WriteLine($"{page}: Processed {item.name}");
    }
}
}
```

So basially the points here are to make sure you let the `SynchronisationContext` do it's job. Inside a console program it should use the `TaskSchedular.Default` which is a `ThreadPool` `SynchronisationContext`. You can always force this by doing:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task.Run(() => new AsyncServerCalls().MainAsyncCall()).Wait();
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

[Reference to Task.Run forcing Default](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,89fc01f3bb88eed9)

One thing you need to remember, which I got into trouble with last week is that you can fire hose the thread pool, i.e. spawn so many tasks that the your process just dies with insane CPU and Memory usage. So you may need to use a Semaphore to just limit the number of threads that going to be created.

I created a solution that processes a single file in multiple parts all at the same time  [Parallel Read](https://github.com/no1melman/ParallelRead/blob/master/ParallelRead/Program.cs) it is still being worked on, but shows the uses of `async` stuff

Just to clarify the parallelism.

When you take a reference to all those tasks:

```
allPages.Add(processPage(page));
```

They all will be started.

When you do:

```
await Task.WhenAll(allPages);
```

This will block the current method execution until all those page processes have been executed (it won't block the current thread though, don't get these confused)

### Danger Zone

If you don't want to block method execution on

```
Task.WhenAll
```

So, you can parallel all page processes for each page, then you can add that `Task` to an overall `List<Task>`.

However, the danger with this is the fire hosing... You are going to limit the number of threads you execute at some point, so where.... well that is up to you but just remember, it will happen at some point.

Comment: When you say: `// dont use static async methods` does this mean on all my async methods? in your example you only removed it from the `MainAsyncCall` method.